# Need localhost SQL Server Database information

Tags: azure-sql-database, u-sql

Need localhost SQL Server Database information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are confusing several concepts:
SQL Server databases are NOT the same as U-SQL databases. U-SQL has its own object model and catalog. So you cannot access a local SQL Server database from U-SQL.

If you are running in Azure, you can create an external data source in the U-SQL catalog through which you can access SQL Server instances in Azure VMs. But you cannot access local SQL Server databases directly.

Answer (score 1):

Since this year you can emulate Azure SQL Database locally:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rf0FvDMm0f0

But keep in mind that this is just for testing.